# Search a text on terminal output on Mac (not using Terminator)

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2

I installed something via Terminal (`iterm2`) on Mac and it showed a whole bunch of commands while installing. I need to look for a specific word to decide my next step?

What should I do?

**Note**:

1. I don't want to search a file. I want to search a text on the terminal output.
2. I cant use `Ctrl + Shift + F`. It for Ubuntu, not for Mac.
3. I don't use Terminator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Damn it! Simply `Ctrl + F` works.

Edit: As @sojim2 pointed out in comments, it's `CMD` + F on mac.

Comment: fyi to others, it's `CMD + F`

Comment: Ohh, good catch. I'll update the answer.